# unset or change a defined constant PHP

Tags: php

assumed i define a variable like this:

```
<?php
define("page", "actual-page");
?>
```

now i have to change this content from `actual-page` to `second-page` how can i realize that?

i try the following methods:

```
<?php
// method 1
    page = "second-page";

// method 2
    define("page", "second-page");

// method 3
    unset(page);
    define("page", "second-page");
?>
```

now my ideas goes out... what can i do else?

Comment: As Juampi answered, by using `define()` you're setting a constant, 'page'. Instead, use a variable: `$page = 'actual-page';`.

Comment: The definition of "constant": _[noun] A situation that does not change._ You should use a variable instead.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you use PHP's define() function, you're not defining a variable, you're defining a constant. Constants can't have their value modified once the script starts executing.

Comment: so... change a defined variable is impossible?

Comment: To make it ultra clear: You CAN change a VARIABLE's value during execution. You CANNOT change a CONSTANT's value during execution.

Comment: yea! this is what i mean! thanks! and sry that i write `variable` and not `constant`!

Answer (score 6):

You can, with the runkit PECL extension:

```
runkit_constant_remove('page');
```

---

http://php.net/runkit_constant_remove
http://github.com/zenovich/runkit

```
sudo pecl install https://github.com/downloads/zenovich/runkit/runkit-1.0.3.tgz
```

---

Update: This module seems to cause trouble with various other things, like the session system for example.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a very late answer, but the question was "now my ideas goes out... what can i do else?"

Here is what you can do "else" - use $GLOBALS:

```
<?php
// method 1
    $GLOBALS['page'] = 'first-page';

// method 2
    $GLOBALS['page'] = "second-page";

// method 3
    $GLOBALS['page'] = 'third-page';
?>
```

I hope it helps. I use it when I do imports and I want specific events not to be fired if the import flag is on for example :)

Comment: `$GLOBALS['page']` is for variable `$page`, instead of constant `page`.

Answer (score -15):

**define** has a third argument (boolean) which override the first defined constant to the second defined constant. Setting the first defined constant to **true**.

```
<?php
define("page", "actual-page", true);
// Returns page = actual-page

define("page", "second-page");
// Returns page = second-page
?>
```

Comment: The third argument is whether the constant should be case sensitive, not whether it can be redefined. http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

Comment: ditto Matt's comment.